# How to count number of lines in a function

Tags: c, perl

I need to count the number of lines in a function in a file.
I have the following inputs.

inputs:

- name of the file,
- name of the function

required output:

- number of lines in the function

Example:

```
int main()
{
    line1;
    line2;
    line3;
}
int func()
{
    line1
    line2
    line3
    line4
    line5
    if(---)  //line 6
    {        //line 7
        line 8
        line 9
    }        //line10
}
```

so the above example should return 10 if we pass the file name and the function name as "func"

Kindly suggest some way to do it...

Comment: i have tried using C languge but it does not look efficient.Is there any other way ??

Comment: More efficient than C? No unless you are an assembly guru that compiler developers were missing for decades or a brilliant hardware designer who can throw in a custom ASIC to do this faster than Intel's chip with all its downsides.

Comment: i mean to say any other scripting language like perl can help ??

Comment: Unless your code has a strict format, this would be hard to do without some type of grammar parser.  If you know it will always be formatted, then sure, Perl may be a good choice.

Comment: You haven't asked a question. You merely presented specs. What's your question? What problem did you run into? Is your question merely "Is this easier in Perl or another language?" Well, you could write a C parser in Perl or in any number of languages. I don't see how it would be easy in any language. You'd probably want to start with an existing parser, so start by looking for one of those, and pick the language it was made for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. code has a strict format, **INDENT** your source files

   > indent  -kr -bap -nce -i8 -ts8 -sob -l80 -ss -bs -npsl -bl  -bli0  file.c
2. awk + substr($0,1,1) match '{' and '}'

   > ```
   >     awk -F"," '{
   >     if( index(v_func,$0)<10 )
   >     {
   >             findfunc=1;
   >     }
   >
   >     if( findfunc == 1)
   >     {
   >        if( substr($0,1,1) == "{" )
   >        {
   >                lineCnt=0;
   >        }
   >        else if(substr($0,1,1) == "}" )
   >        {
   >                print lineCnt;
   >        }
   >        else
   >        {
   >                lineCnt = lineCnt+1;
   >        }
   >     } }' v_func=$2 $1
   > ```

Comment: The `indent` tip = awesome.

Comment: this looks useful; I wonder if you could adjust it to show the full shell script (specifying, I'm guessing, that it gets invoked as count_lines_in_func.sh file.c [func_name]), and make it so that with no function name given it prints each function and how many lines were in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys,re

if len(sys.argv)<3:
    print "Usage: %s filename functionname"%(sys.argv[0])
    exit(0)

f=open(sys.argv[1],"r")
func=sys.argv[2]
linec=0
braces=1
lines=f.readlines()

for i in range(len(lines)):
    if re.match(".{4}"+func,lines[i]):
        break

lines=[s.strip() for s in lines]
lines=[s for s in lines if len(s)!=0]

for k in lines[i+2:]:
    if k=="{":
        braces+=1
    if k=="}":
        braces-=1
    if braces<=0:
        break
    linec+=1

print linec
```

Comment: this python script should print number of lines of code for the given example atleast

Comment: as long as it's that exact example, not one with multiple braces per line, or string/character constants containing braces, or... etc.

Answer (score 0):

> Suggest someway to do it..

Very roughly:

```
a) assume this is pedantic exercise for class, so ignore tricky bits like macros
b) open "filename"
c) read file into memory
d) strstr() for "function"
e) scan until you hit "{"
f) for(bracecount=1; bracecount > 0; )
g) ++ on {, -- }, skip char constants, skip comments, keep newline count
h) print newline count
```

Comment: True. Delete the quotes and then it make sense.

Comment: No it doesn't. There's no string you could pass to `strstr` to identify a function.

Comment: Of course, one can make arbitrarily complex examples until a full C parser with pre-processor is required. The question here is: what is the teacher looking for, not what Sheldon would approve of.

Comment: What you posted isn't something that works within constraints. What you posted is something that NEVER works.